# Date query in java for mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to make a query in java to search mongo for a date. To search on compass this query works
 {"createdTime": ISODate('2018-10-10 15:01:40.354')}

Would anyone know how to put this query into a BasicDBObject query which i could then use like this:

mongoCollection.find(query)

Comment: BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("createdTime", dateObject);

Answer (score 0):

I hope that will help you.

First we insert:

```
public void insertMany(MongoCollection<Document> coll) throws Exception {
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Document newValue0 = new Document("a", "1").append("b", "2").append("c", "3").append("x", new Date());
    Document newAlphs1 = new Document("a", "2").append("b", "5").append("c", "55").append("x", sdf.parse("2018-08-10 14:23:35"));
    Document newAlphs2 = new Document("a", "3").append("b", "9").append("c", "46").append("x", sdf.parse("2018-07-09 14:23:35"));
    Document newAlphs3 = new Document("a", "3").append("b", "9").append("c", "46").append("x", sdf.parse("2018-06-15 14:23:35"));
    coll.insertMany(Arrays.asList(newValue0, newAlphs1, newAlphs2, newAlphs3));
}
```

After we find:

```
public void findByFilterDates(MongoCollection<Document> coll) throws Exception {
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    // for equal
    Bson filter = Filters.and(Filters.eq("x",sdf.parse("2018-06-15 14:23:35")));
    List<Document> docs = coll.find(filter).into(new ArrayList<Document>());

    //for greater than 
    Bson filter2 = Filters.and(Filters.gt("x",sdf.parse("2018-08-10 14:23:35")));
    List<Document> docs2 = coll.find(filter2).into(new ArrayList<Document>());

    //for greater than 
    Bson filter3 = Filters.and(Filters.gt("x",sdf.parse("2018-08-10 14:23:00")), Filters.lt("x",sdf.parse("2018-06-15 14:23:50")));
    List<Document> docs3 = coll.find(filter3).into(new ArrayList<Document>());

}
```